# NSCollectionView doesn’t show its contents

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscollectionview

What I want to do is create a simple NSCollectionView in my application and populate it with images.

I have managed to design/link everything in Interface Builder and I try to load an array of whatever into the collection view so that it will display the view (nib-file) linked to it in the interface builder, but I had no luck so far. There is no way I can make to collection view display anything.

```
 NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [array addObject:@"Test"];
 [array addObject:@"Test"];
 [array addObject:@"Test"];
 [array addObject:@"Test"];
 [array addObject:@"Test"];

 [myCollectionView setContent:array];
```

I have followed 2 guides I found on Google but they seem to be deprecated, they wont work in Xcode 4.

I'm desperate please help me. I just want to make the NSCollectionView to display anything. I'm running Lion and xcode 4.1

Comment: Did you define an appropriate NSCollectionViewItem for your collection view?

Comment: Yes. The interface builder created and linked one for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

In order for the NSCollectionView to show anything, the NSArray that you provide to it must have `nil` as the last element.

After that the NSCollectionView was displaying beautifully.

Comment: Except that `NSArray` cannot have `nil` elements. Maybe you’re talking about one of the methods that take a `nil`-terminated list of objects as opposed to the example in your question?

Comment: I'm talking about `NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Bla",@"Bla",@"Bla",nil];` And the last element is a `nil` as you can see.

Comment: @Dimme That's exactly what Bavarious said -- the `NSArray` does NOT contain a `nil`, the `initWithObjects:` method takes a nil-terminated list of objects to put into the array.